# Issues with PIFM Numbers Station tutorial/project

Tags: pifm

I am trying to get the following PiFM numbers station project working:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZx9aB1jkH8
https://github.com/korn101/PiNumberStation

I'm running it on a Pi Model B+ and when I run sudo python PiNS.py  I am getting one long tone playing on the radio).

I've checked all the .wavs supplied with the github folder but it is not any of them. I've also changed the message.txt file but I'm still getting the same tone.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I'm still struggling with this if anyone can lend a hand!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is having a problem with this in the future...you must use the original raspberry Pi 1 and it will work!

Cheers,

paul

Answer (score -1):

had the exact same issue and brought it up to the group.  See this thread.

Also beware that this is likely illegal use of the pi as a transmitter, but it is fun to hear over FM bands.

[PiFm on raspi-zero](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/52069/50404)

Comment: OK I jumped the gun a bit there, different application of pifm.  I had issues initially with only a single tone playing and together we fixed it.  If that doesn't solve youe issue I'll remove my answer

Comment: Hey bk79, thanks for the reply...not sure if that is the issue and I am a bit stuck (and not technically proficient enough)..I'm really trying to get idea/logic  of the PINumbers station working...if I can get it to this level I can then start switching audio and adapting etc...if you have any more suggestions great...but thanks again anyway!